# DVD drive tray button

Tags: eject

I am using ubuntu 14.04 LTS. My problem is that the open/close button on the DVD-RW drive tray dies after booting ubuntu... There is no hardware malfunction, the button works fine before booting ubuntu. The 'eject' command works fine, the eject button on the device's options on the disks management utility works fine as well. So I made a launcher executing the 'eject -T' command. It will very useful if I could figure out how to use the open/close button on the device's tray. I also tried adding the 'dev.cdrom.lock=0' line in sysctl.conf, but it worked only for 2-3 times. Any advice would be very helpful, thanks in advance!